# Show fields on webform based on a value in the session

Tags: 7, webforms

I want to use a webform to do a feedback form but want it to act on data provided by the user. That is, if the user has answered a question about location which is stored in a session, then I want to show a webform field, otherwise don't show the field at all. Any ideas on if this is possible and how to do it in webform?

Thanks.

Comment: Try assigning a template for your form, so that you can work on that tpl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try somewhere in your webform-form-[NID].tpl.php

```
hide($form['submitted']['your-field-name']);
if($_SESSION['your_value'] == 'what it should be') {
   show($form['submitted']['your-field-name']);
}
```